# TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, datetime.date found

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get  a date of an origin invoice after doing a special process to this invoice because the first date changed when i try to do this process but i faced this error when am trying to doing this process :

```
 in get_origins_date_invoice TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, datetime.date found.
```

this is the code to get my origin date:

```
@property
def origin_date(self):
    if isinstance(self.origin, self.__class__):
        return self.origin.invoice.invoice_date
    else:
        return " "

def get_origins_date_invoice(self, name):
    return ', '.join(set(filter(None,
                (l.origin_date for l in self.lines))))
```

and this is the error displayed:

```
in get_origins_date_invoice
    (l.origin_date for l in self.lines))))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, datetime.date found.
```

How can i solve that please.

Comment: According to [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), `join` function has to be given `Iterable[str]` argument. `TypeError` will be raised if provided not string object. `(str(l.origin_date) for l in self.lines)` should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The `join()` method of the built-in `str` type in Python accepts iterables returning type `str`, so the path in `origin_date()` with a non-string return type is incompatible with this.

To fix this, you can either change `origin_date()` like this:

```
def origin_date(self):
    if isinstance(self.origin, self.__class__):
        return str(self.origin.invoice.invoice_date)
    else:
        return " "
```

... or change `get_origins_date_invoice()` like this:

```
def get_origins_date_invoice(self, name):
    return ', '.join(set(filter(None,
                (str(l.origin_date) for l in self.lines))))
```

Comment: I have tried that solution and this error gone but then it gives me another error when i want to print it in my report it gives me this error:

    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: Can you edit your question to add the code that gives the new error?